# After adding user to a group, can't tell if I'm in it or not?

Tags: linux, groups

I added a group called developers

```
sudo groupadd developers
```

then added myself to that group

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G developers nick.weavers
```

Then I issued the command groups to check I'd been added, but got this

```
$ groups
nick.weavers wheel
```

However, if I issued the groups command with the name of the user I wanted to check like this

```
$ groups nick.weavers
nick.weavers : nick.weavers wheel developers
```

I am show to be in the developers group, but am I? Why do the two commands show different results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the groups man page (CentOS 7):

> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
> Print  group  memberships  for each USERNAME or, if no USERNAME is specified,
> for the current process (which may differ if the groups database has changed).
> ```

Adding yourself to a group does not affect the groups for processes already running, like your existing shell.  This means you need to establish a new connection to see and use the permissions of the new group.